# Is the meaning of "to grant the freedom to" closer to "to permit"/"to allow" or closer to "to facilitate"?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What is meant by saying that you grant X the freedom to do Y?

1. that X can do Y and you are free to present obstacles other than outright forbidding X to do Y
2. that X can do Y and you **must not interfere**
3. that X can do Y and you must facilitate/aid X in doing Y
4. something else

Comment: Having money can *grant you the freedom/facilitate/allow you* to follow your own desires. The exact meanings of all these terms depend heavily on *exact context*. It's fairly pointless to debate which are inherently closer in meaning to which others devoid of context, since in many contexts they may actually be equivalent.

Comment: Fair enough, but you changed the use a bit ("having money" is not a person). What I am trying to find is if person Z granting X the freedom to do Y can in any way imply that Z must actually aid X in doing Y. As I see it, the answer is No, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Whether the freedom/facilitation/etc. comes from a sentient agent, a circumstance, or something more abstract such as an *ability* is all part of the context. You seek a semantic distinction between different ways of expressing things that doesn't really exist outside of context.

Comment: It disappoints me that this was question was marked as off-topic. It doesn't really affect me since I already received some excellent answers. I find the reason given to be superficial. The question is not fit for Eng Lang Learners because I was not seeking the meaning but the intended nuance of the phrase. And while the accepted answer uses commonly-available references, the meaning of the phrase is not necessarily the sum of its parts and I felt it required a clarification.(which I consider I received)

Comment: Believe me when I tell you that I know how disappointing it is to have a question closed. Your question will likely meet ELU's standards if you *simply* add some evidence of the research you've done. That's the reason the question was put on hold and it's not superficial (or personal), the members voted to put it "on hold" in order to maintain the site's standards. The hold gives you 5 days to amend your question--add research and expand on your explanation why a simple dictionary doesn't solve your difficulty--the better (or more clear) your question, the better the responses you'll get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freedictionary.com defines **grant**:

> 1.To **allow** or **consent** to the fulfillment of (something requested):
>
> grant permission to speak frankly; grant a request.
>
> 2.
>   a To give or confer officially or formally:
>
> *grant voting rights to citizens; grant diplomatic immunity.*

It defines freedom in several ways:

> 1. a. The condition of not being in prison or captivity: gave the
>      prisoners their freedom.
>
>    **b. The condition of being free of restraints, especially the ability to act without control or interference by another or by
>      circumstance:**
>
> *In retirement they finally got the freedom to travel.*
>
> 2. a. The condition of not being controlled by another nation or political power; political independence.
>
>    b. The condition of not being subject to a despotic or oppressive
>      power; civil liberty.
>
>    c. The condition of not being constrained or restricted in a specific
>      aspect of life by a government or other power:
>
>    *freedom of assembly.*
>
>    d. The condition of not being a slave.
> 3. a. The condition of not being affected or restricted by a given circumstance or condition: freedom from want.
>
>    b. The condition of not being bound by established conventions or
>      rules:
>
>    *The new style of painting gave artists new freedoms.*
> 4. The capacity to act by choice rather than by determination, as from fate or a deity; free will:
>
>    *We have the freedom to do as we please all afternoon.*
> 5. The right to unrestricted use; full access:
>
>    *was given the freedom of their research facilities.*
> 6. Ease or facility of movement: loose sports clothing, giving the wearer freedom.**strong text**

Based on the definitions and the options you give, it seems the best answer is

### 4. *You have **permitted** X to do Y and you will not **interfere***.

Technically, granting X freedom does not speak to whether X actually **can** do Y.

The interaction of **individual** *freedoms* is a complex menagerie of considerations.  In oversight situations, an overseer grants freedom with the implied understanding that she can intervene when necessary to protect the interests of the organization, which retains discrete **corporate** freedoms. This complexity is why we put contracts in writing. We pay lawyers big bucks to review contracts before we sign them, and litigate them when we believe they have been broken. Defining the freedoms we grant to others in specific detail is a fine art that goes ***well beyond*** defining the word *freedom*. The rest of the questions are above my pay grade :-)

Comment: Welcome to ELU, @Ed Miller. I see that was your first answer and a good one! Concise, clear, and cited.

Comment: Great answer Ed Miller. Thank you. I never took into account the possibility X might not be able to do Y. The options I offered were merely a guideline. I added option 4 because I anticipated the answer might be more complex. I am now trying to harmonize this answer with @Mark s answer. Care to comment on my comment to his answer?

Comment: Additionally, to clarify. If X is incapable of doing Y, under no circumstance can it be implied that you must also aid X in doing Y, merely by granting X the freedom to do Y?

Comment: Also to clarify what is meant by interference here is a less than ideal example. Case 1: Building owner Z grants wheelchair bound person X freedom to enter the building. **Afterwards** Z replaces a dirt ramp with stair steps at the entrance.  Case 2: The stair steps were there in the first place. Case 3: X is healthy and is granted the freedom to enter. Then, after the stair steps were built, X becomes wheelchair bound. (Assume the building is not a public space with building regulation requiring ramps)

Comment: Your added examples go beyond *granting freedom* and enter into *granting aid* (or commitment to aid).

Comment: @GoodA.M.: "beyond granting freedom and enter into granting aid" Indeed, the difference between the 3 case is just the order of events. The issue raised is how fuzzy is the line between "to not interfere" and "to aid". Ed Miller is right that the complexity is why we put contracts in writing. However the discussion where I needed the meaning of this term is more philosophical in nature than contractual/legal.

Answer (score 1):

**To “grant the freedom” is closer to “to permit”/“to allow” than “to facilitate.” As to the four choices you offered: 4. something else.**

> **GRANT** (transitive *verb*)
>
> **1** *a*: to consent to carry out for a person: allow fulfillment of (*grant* a request)
>   *b*: to permit as a right, privilege, or favor (luggage allowances *granted* to passengers)
>   **2**: to bestow or transfer formally (*grant* a scholarship to a student); specifically: to give the possession or title of by a deed 
>   **3** *a*: to be willing to concede
>
> **Origin of GRANT**
>
> Middle English, from Anglo-French *granter*, *graanter*, from Vulgar Latin *credentare*, from Latin *credent*-, *credens*, present participle of *credere* to believe—more at creed
>
> **First Known Use: 13th century**
>
> **Synonyms**: acknowledge, agree, allow, concede, confess, fess (up), admit, own (up to)
>
> [**Merriam-Webster Dictionary** *online*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grant)

To *grant*, in your context (**definition b**), is to award, bestow, or give permission to proceed in a given endeavor or domain of action. ***Grant* carries no *explicit* connotations of either adding or removing other conditions or contingencies affecting fulfillment of the granted action or endeavor.** That said, “*granting permission*” does carry *the implication* that the one who has bestowed such permission is not intent upon impeding (but rather, facilitating) progress toward fulfillment of the *granted* action or endeavor.

Answer (score -2):

It means choice #1.

If I permit X do do Y, then I give X my own personal permission. But if I give X the freedom to do Y, then that means I have the authority make it official.

As an example: If you permit me to leave the country, you're probably my parent giving me permission to go on holiday. However, if you give me the freedom to leave the country, you're probably the government telling me that I won't be stopped at customs.

Comment: Therefore requiring passports and customs checks (interference) does not negate the freedom granted. Or is it that this is a conditional freedom as in "the government grants me the freedom to leave the country as long as I carry a passport, and follow instructions at customs checks" and other than the conditions already mentioned they must not interfere?

Comment: *Freedom* is a ***huge*** word with lots of implications. Mark's implication seem legitimate but not definitive. The *freedom* of a minor to leave the country requires multiple interdependent grants of freedom. Possession of a passport documents the government's **permission** to leave the country. A letter of permission documents the **permission** of parents not escorting their children. A visa is usually required to enter another country before freedom is attained. Incidentally, the government does not **grant** freedom (remember inalienable rights?); it should **protect** freedom.

Comment: @GoodA.M. : You make many good points. This example is not really fit, since it gets complicated quick. As I mentioned in a comment to my question, what I want to know is: if "person Z granting X the freedom to do Y" can in any way imply that "Z must actually aid X in doing Y"? Each time I look at the question, the answer is No, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Granting freedom to another does not necessarily require surrendering your own freedom. The grantees demands for aid fulfill the proverb: "Give a camel an inch and he'll take an ell (six hand breadths or approx. a yard)."